# ComplexListPlot not ploting

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, complex

In a nutshell i have to plot a sequence of complex numbers to roughly see if it converges or not.
I've created the list using the following

```
uno=Table[(2 i^n - n)/(3 + i)^n, {n, 100}]
```

then i used

```
ComplexListPlot[uno]
```

but it just throws me the same list that table, not plotting anything.
Im using Mathematica 11.3.
Thank you in advance for any information that helps my case.

Comment: Your variable `i` is undefined. If you intend `Sqrt[-1]` use `I`

Comment: ComplexListPlot was introduced in version 12.

Comment: @BobHanlon, thank you, i just changed that.

Comment: @Carl Woll, i didnt knew that. i changed the comand 'Complexlistplot' to just 'ListPlot' and it plotted the sequence but im unsure if it correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
uno = Table[(2 I^n - n)/(3 + I)^n, {n, 100}];

ListPlot[ReIm@uno, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The points are tightly clustered near the origin.

```
ListPlot[ReIm@uno, Frame -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}]
```

[image]

To look for convergence, you might want to look at the plot of the [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html)

```
ListPlot[Abs@uno, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Abs@uno, Frame -> True,
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really usefull, specially the Abs command. Thank you very much.